# Привязка ширины DialogHostContent к размеру экрана?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

Как задать ширину Grid 60% в DialogHost от размеров окна? И при изменении размеров окна изменился размер Grid.

```xml
<MaterialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="DialogHost" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignEmbeddedDialogHost}" Margin="0" Panel.ZIndex="1000" DialogMargin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Focusable="False" IsManipulationEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <MaterialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
        <Grid></Grid>
    </MaterialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
</MaterialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Comment: UI - это XAML, хотите красиво, просто и элегантно, то забудьте про C# код вовсе для создания UI!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Поймите меня, не могу я создавать сотни Grid-ов и других различных элементов в XAML и многие должны создаваться в зависимости от условий.

Comment: А это противоречит моим словам выше? Делаете `ItemsControl`, задаете ему нужный вид, привязываете к коллекции и радуетесь, вот у вас и сотня гридов. Условия также, либо тип объекта и в зависимости от типа нужный вид, либо триггеры.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Но элементы все ровно создаются в C#

Comment: Лучший алгоритм вам предложил @EvgeniyZ , но если хочется извращений: получаете размер вашего окна, умножаете его на 0.6 и присваиваете его DataGrid (Width и Height).

Comment: @AlexeyVesker Если я изменю размер экрана то размер останется тот же.

Comment: Отловите событие изменения размера окна и по той же схеме обновите Grid

Comment: Смотрите... В C# вы создаете простые классы, которые содержат в себе лишь нужную информацию (например класс "человек" со свойствами Имя, Фамилия, Возраст), вы с ними работает, как и с любыми другими классами, вся ваша логика становиться отделена от UI, а WPF, если вы верно все привяжите, сам за вас нарисует UI. То есть сейчас вы всю работу за рисование берете на себя, вы делаете уйму лишнего с уймой костылей, когда этого можно было бы избежать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Как вы привязкой сделаете что рисовался либо DatePicker либо TextBox либо еще что-то?

Comment: Поймите, что в WPF такие вещи как "привязка" и "XAML разметка", это не некая "фича добавленная кем-то и когда-то после релиза", а самая основная вещь всего WPF проекта, на которой Microsoft базировали и строили все остальное. Если вы этим не пользуетесь, то тогда логичный вопрос: А зачем вам WPF проект? Делайте тогда WinForms, набросаете быстро контролов, нагенерите оставшиеся через C# и будете радоваться, но WPF... Все же надо использовать так, как положено.

Comment: `Как вы привязкой сделаете что рисовался либо DatePicker ` - элементарно, делаете коллекцию из разный классов, ее привязываете, а в XAML пишете `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type МойКласс}">(тут задаете нужный вид, с нужными привязками)</DataTemplate>` и все, если XAML увидит, что он работает с указанным типом, то ему будет присвоен данный вид.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Как Вы это перенесете в XAML?

https://pastebin.com/KRVXkLC5

Comment: Вешаете в обработчик события изменения размеров окна пересчет размеров грида в рикселях, и готово. Но лучше учите xaml, вот [пример простой разметки интрефейса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1215334/373567).

Comment: @aepot Точно, спасибо. Я XAML в своем проекте использую.

Comment: `Как Вы это перенесете в XAML` - все базовые вещи я вам уже сказал, а именно `Привязки`, `ItemsSource` (или любой другой контрол), `DataTemplate`, `Триггеры`, ну и `Стили`. Все что угодно можно решить правилами WPF проекта, все, нету такой задачи, которую нельзя было бы решить через него.

Comment: [Пример работы с TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61731042/12888024).

Comment: Помниться тоже давал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/826727/220553). Ну а так, посмотрите на свой сейчас код и ответьте себе на вопрос - он вам нравиться? Мне допустим нет, ибо у вас смешано все в одну кучу, в одном куске кода вы и с UI работаете и с базой, и с данными из базы и куча чего еще. Почему бы просто не попробовать это улучшить? Начните распутывать этот клубок кода, разделите его на отдельные части, где одна будет отвечать за базу, другая за вывод данных, просто хотя бы следуйте правилам SOLID, а потом и вдруг привязки станут для вас с XAML полезными...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Хорошо, помогите пожалуйста с этим - https://pastebin.com/7U6e8PKr.
Как сделать Grid Width 60%?

Comment: o_O я же вам показал, как, но вы ответили `Спасибо, за ответ, но к сожалению, это не то что мне нужно.`, и опять то же самое спрашиваете.

Comment: @aepot А как это тут применить?

Comment: @aepot И что будет мой Grid разделен на две колонки с соотношение 3:2.Но когда я изменю размер окна то размер Grid не измениться.

Comment: Откуда вы знаете, что не изменится? Просто используйте вложенный грид вместо внешнего, он и будет 60%.

Comment: @aepot Если в ставить мой DialogHost в вложенный Grid то размер будет статический, а затемненный фон будет на 60% экрана.

Comment: Ничего не понял, DialogHost - это разве не отдельное окно? Как его можно вставить в грид? И у вас тег в вопросе про WPF, а не про MaterialDesign, у которого могут быть свои причуды.

Comment: @aepot Нет, вот - https://intellitect.com/material-design-in-xaml-dialog-host/, Вы ж мне вроде присылали эту статью. DialogHost - это элемент Material Design.

Comment: Ну так, диалог в оверлее окна, оне не предназначен, чтобы его засовывать в грид, точнее будет тот эффект, про который вы говорите. Чего именно вы хотите добиться?

Comment: @aepot Я хочу что бы width Grid который в DialogContent равнялся 60% от размера окна.

Comment: @aepot Так что Вы мне сможете помочь?

Comment: Если вам претит XAML (я вас понимаю), можете попробовать [Ammy](http://www.ammyui.com/) - гораздо более легковесный JSON-синтаксис. [Тут](http://rsdn.org/forum/nemerle/6670196) обсуждение. [Тут](https://vimeo.com/198873582) видео.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через C# не умею (да и зачем уметь?), а через XAML как-то так.

```aml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="SixtyPercent">
        <!-- 60% -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
<MaterialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="DialogHost" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignEmbeddedDialogHost}" Margin="0" Panel.ZIndex="1000" DialogMargin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Focusable="False" IsManipulationEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <MaterialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
        <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SixtyPercent}">
        </Grid>
    </MaterialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
</MaterialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, но к сожалению, это не то что мне нужно.

Comment: @Nastia обновил ответ, попробуйте рядом с гридом его поместить, и привязаться у размеру колонки.