# Binding с помощью c#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть такая привязка:

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=EditTableSize}"
```

как мне сделать такую привязку через c#?

Comment: @mik.ov просто нужно

Comment: Мы ведь с вами говорили [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1222842/220553), что в WPF использовать C# для работы с UI это плохо, вы вроде это поняли, вам показали, как решить ту задачу на чистом XAML, и на тебе, вы опять лезете в это болото, делая себе опять лишнюю работу, ну зачем?

Comment: `как мне сделать такую привязку через c#?` - а зачем? А вообще всё это есть в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам ну очень нужно то вот так:

```
someObjectname.
    SetBinding(WidthProperty, new Binding("ActualWidth") { ElementName = "EditTableSize" });
```

Однако, вместо `WidthProperty` укажите класс в который необходимо устанавливать свойство. Например в моем случае это `ContentPresenter`. e.g:

```
someObjectname.
    SetBinding(ContentPresenter.WidthProperty,
               new Binding("ActualWidth") { ElementName = "EditTableSize" });
```

Comment: К сожалению, оба способа не работают. Я подобное пробовала.

Comment: Почему вы так решили?

Comment: Возможна сделать привязку с ключом, типа чтобы можно привязать по FindResource?

Comment: Как это относится к вашему вопросу?

Comment: Я проверила только что.

Comment: `Как это относится к вашему вопросу?` Может так можно сделать привязку через c#.

Comment: Я не понимаю как ваш комментарий относится и вашему вопросу???

Comment: Мне просто нужно както сделать привязку у елемента который я создала в c#

Comment: @Nastia Еще раз повторю вам, вы делаете ерунду! Если вы не знаете как правильно решить вашу задачу, то описывайте конкретно вашу конечную задачу, а не то, какой "костыль" вы придумали. Самые элементарные привязки по типу `public string Text {get;set;}` <-> `<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Text" />` или `public string[] Names {get;set;}` <-> `<ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Names}"/>` (`<ListBox ItemsSource= "{Binding Names}"/>`) решаю почти все задачи, без необходимости использования UI в коде.